# Specific yet simple code for player movement not working as intended (XNA)

Tags: c#, xna

**Problem**: Sometimes, when my fighter's running in one direction (because Im'm holding direction button like A,D,Left or Right), and I quicly release button for that direction and press button for opposite direction, the fighter continues to run in the first mentioned direction. This doesn't happen all the time, it's "*random*". Also, this has nothing to do with jumping/falling, because it doesn't matter if fighter's in air or not.
I have 4 classes in which fighter movement is regulated in update methods:

**Input** class, just some functions

```
public static void UpdateNew(GameTime gt)
{
    // fires before any other update is called (before player/level/fighter update...)
    frameTime = (float)gt.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
    ksNew = Keyboard.GetState();
    msNew = Mouse.GetState();
}
public static void UpdateOld()
{
     // fires after every other update is called (after player/level/fighter update...)
    ksOld = ksNew;
    msOld = msNew;
    scrollValue = msOld.ScrollWheelValue;
}
public static bool Down(Keys k)
{ return ksNew.IsKeyDown(k); }
```

**Player** class:

```
Fighter fighter; //set in constructor, it's not null
public void Update()
{
    fighter.RunDirection = Input.Down(rightK).ToInt() - Input.Down(leftK).ToInt();
    fighter.Jump = Input.Down(jumpK);
    fighter.Punch = Input.Clicked(punchK);
}
// where .ToInt() converts bool to 1 if it's true, and to 0 if it's not true
```

**Fighter** class

```
public int              RunDirection
{ set { runMultiplier = MathHelper.Clamp(value, -1, 1); } }

public override void    Update              (float elTime, List<Entity> entities)
{
    // region: checks for jump, works fine

    AddForce(
         // X - Horizontal Force
         ((Math.Abs(Force.X) < runSpeed) ? runMultiplier * runSpeed * 5 * elTime : 0) // movement controls
         + ((runMultiplier == 0) ? -Force.X.Sign() * runSpeed * 5 * elTime : 0) // traction when not moving
         ,
         // Y - Vertical Force
         ((!canJump) ? 900 * elTime : 0) // gravity
         - jumpDecreasingSpeed * elTime // jump
         );

    // region: Check collision and puts force.X or force.Y to 0 when it's colliding with other 
    // entities and put's player next to that entity

    //set bool that stores last direction of looking (left/right)
    if (runMultiplier != 0) lookingRight = runMultiplier > 0;

    //checks if animation should be changed (idle, running, jumping or falling)
    CheckAnimation();

    //update currently playing animation
    currentAnim.Update(elTime);

    //stop fighters horisontal movement if it's small enough
    if (Math.Abs(Force.X) < 1) AddForce(-Force.X, 0);

    // after all calculations, move fighter by the force that is currently imacting him.
    Position += Force * elTime;
}
```

**Level** class

```
public void         Update          (float elTime)
{
    // PLAYERS
    p1.Update(); // updates only controls, as mentioned above, not the fighter itself.
    p2.Update();

    // update ENTITIES, player's fighters, and walls (their update method is empty)
    // player's fighters are added to maps "entities" list.
    for (int i = 0; i < map.entities.Count; i++)
        map.entities[i].Update(elTime, map.entities.Where(q => q != map.entities[i]).ToList());
}
```

**Brief update order for each frame**
GameMainUpdate
---Input.UpdateNew
---Level.Update
------Player.Update
------Fighter.Update
---------Check if player want's you to move, and add force (velocity)
---------Check collision, set force to 0 moving if colliding
---------when all calculations are done, add force to current position
---Input.UpdateOld

**Question:** Why is this happening? Why is it so "*random*"? I understand that it happends for a reason, but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: The line `fighter.RunDirection = Input.Down(rightK).ToInt() - Input.Down(leftK).ToInt();` looks very odd to me, considering that `Input.Down` is declared as `bool`.  What are you trying to do there?

Comment: the RunDirection (in Fighter class mentioned as runMultiplier) determines if the fighter will move or not. It's values can be -1, 0 and 1. So, when moving my fighter, I always add some force to it on the X axis. that force is actualy this: runMultiplier * runSpeed. Now, run speed will be something like 800, and runMultiplier will be -1, 0 or 1, that translates as: -1: move fighter to the left by runSpeed, 0: don't move fighter, 1: move fighter to the right by runSpeed. The line you mentioned translates as: Run multiplier = (Holding left? use 1, not? use 0) - (Holding right? use 1, not? use 0)

Comment: so, if i'm holding just left key, RunDirection = 0 - 1 = -1, and when that goes to fighter update class, he will move like this: addForce( 'runMultiplier=' -1 * 'runSpeed=' 800, ...); This is how it moves to left. Same goes for right: RunDirection = 1 - 0. So, when I'm holding both buttons, or not holding any, RunDirection (runMultiplier) will be 0, and the player won't move, because 0 * 800 = 0. I hope I explained it so you understand the logic behind it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible scenario that causes it is when `Math.Abs(Force.X) >= runSpeed` then you add 0 force.

If Force.X >= runSpeed then 0

runMultiplier == 0 (false due to immediate switch) then 0

AddForce(0+0)

```
     // X - Horizontal Force
     ((Math.Abs(Force.X) < runSpeed) ? runMultiplier * runSpeed * 5 * elTime : 0) // movement controls
     + ((runMultiplier == 0) ? -Force.X.Sign() * runSpeed * 5 * elTime : 0) // traction when not moving
```

Then this will never be executed because `Math.Abs(Force.X) >= 1` (I assume runspeed  is >= 1).

```
//stop fighters horisontal movement if it's small enough
if (Math.Abs(Force.X) < 1) AddForce(-Force.X, 0);
```

This is a possible reason why switching keys within a 1 frame buffer where the one direction is immediately replaced by the other can net you a force of 0; which would cause the fighter to continue in the previous direction.

Comment: Did you get the reputation? I don't know how to send it to you. Eill you get it when the bounty ends?

Comment: No problem, I did get it. Thanks for making sure.